# Minimizing $\frac{1-c}{1-\frac{(a-b)^3}{(1-a)^2} - \frac{(b-c)^3}{(a-b)^2} - \frac{c^3}{b^2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, approximation, mathematica

I am interested in approximating the minimum of

$$\dfrac{1-c}{1-\dfrac{(a-b)^3}{(1-a)^2} - \dfrac{(b-c)^3}{(a-b)^2} - \dfrac{c^3}{b^2}}$$
Subject to $0 < \frac{a-b}{1-a} < \frac{b-c}{a-b} < \frac{c}{b} < 1$ and $0\leq a,b,c \leq 1$. The minimum is $\approx 0.82$ numerically, but not sure how to show this. In particular, I'm interested in a lower bound.

Comment: I think the infimum is $\approx 0.8187432025$ which is the unique real root of $49424013\,{x}^{9}-184941468\,{x}^{8}+293709726\,{x}^{7}-249659172\,{x}
^{6}+117868365\,{x}^{5}-27976104\,{x}^{4}+2150064\,{x}^{3}-57024\,{x}^
{2}+6912\,x-1024
 = 0$.

Comment: Let $x = \frac{a - b}{1 - a}$ etc. The condition becomes $0 < x < y < z < 1$. We want to find the infimum  of ${\frac {xy+x+1}{-x{y}^{3}-{x}^{3}+3\,xy+x+1}}$.

Comment: @RiverLi But aren't the variables dependent? i.e $y$ is not free when $x$ is fixed?

Comment: Also, can you clarify on where the polynomial comes from?

Comment: You can solve $a, b, c$ from $x = \frac{a - b}{1 - a}$ etc.

Comment: @RiverLi What I mean is, in the original problem, $a,b,c$ are free, but once you parametrize on $x,y,z$, the variables are not independent (free), so the minimum of your expression should be less than the actual minimum?

Comment: Just do it. And put your attempt in the main body. In this site, you need to provide some information such as source, attempt etc.